# Firebase Pub/sub trigger: executing multiple times sporadically

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

We're using Firebase for our app that needs to process a some data and then send out a series of e-mails after their data has been decided.

Right now I'm triggering a single handler via CRON (which uses pub/sub) that processes the data and then publishes a series of messages to a different pub/sub topic. That topic in turn has a similar trigger function that goes through a few processes and then sends an single email per execution.

```
// Triggered by CRON task
const cronPublisher = functions.pubsub.topic('queue-emails').onPublish(async () => {
   //processing
   ... 
   // Publish to other topic
   await Promise.all(
     emails.map((email) =>
        publisher.queueSendOffer(email)
     )
  );
});

// Triggered by above, at times twice
const sendEmail = functions.pubsub.topic('send-email').onPublish(async () => {
   //processing and send email
});
```

The issue I'm running into is that the 2nd topic trigger *at times* is executed more than once, sending two identical emails. The main potential cause I've come across by way of Google just involves long execution times resulting in timeouts, and retries. This *shouldn't* be the case since our acknowledgment timeout is configured to 300 seconds and the execution times never exceed ~12 seconds.

Also, the Firebase interface doesn't seem to give you any control over how this acknowledgment is sent.

This CRON function runs everyday and the issue only occurs every 4-5 days, but then it duplicates every single email.

Any thoughts?

Appreciated.

Comment: Cloud Functions doesn't give you an exactly-once guarantee on your function executions.  It gives you an at-least-once guarantee, which implies that your function may get executed more than once, but that should be rare.  In any event, your function should be "idempotent" - resistant to being called multiple times.  You may have to persist some data in a database to ensure that your function bails if some work has already been done.

Comment: Yeah, I expected there may be an odd occurrence here and there, but this issue definitely hasn't fit that description. Every so-many days every single message is duplicated. I expect I'll need to rethink the architecture a bit but I'm trying to understand exactly what's happening.

Comment: Hey Doug where is the documentation that supports what you are saying about an at least once guarantee, which implies it may get executed more than once?

Comment: How do you make a pub sub function atomic?

Answer (score 1):

If 'every single message' is duplicated, perhaps it is your 'cronPublisher' function that is being called twice?  Cloud Pubsub offers at least once semantics, so your job should be tolerant to this https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery.

If you were to persist some information in a firebase transaction that this cron event had been received, and check that before publishing, you could prevent duplicate publishing to the "send-email" topic.

Comment: It occurred to me but the logs indicate that the cronPublisher() function is only executing once; hence the confusion. Good call on the transaction, I may go that direction.